# ebay API GetOrders shows wrong result

Tags: ebay-api

My objective is to list user's transactions (both sales and purchases).

I am using GetOrders and specifying a time range to and the call executes successfully but returns 0 transactions, whereas the user I am querying for has multiple purchases on their account.

Let me get a bit more specific. Here is the code that I am using:

```
<GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>......</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<CreateTimeFrom>2009-04-05T05:02:03</CreateTimeFrom>
<CreateTimeTo>2011-12-23T00:02:44</CreateTimeTo>
</GetOrdersRequest>​
```

---

And even using the API test tool (Hence, the problem is not language specific) it delivers 0 results:

```
<GetOrdersResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<Timestamp>2011-12-23T00:05:32.753Z</Timestamp>
<Ack>Success</Ack>
<Version>753</Version>
<Build>E753_CORE_BUNDLED_14214525_R1</Build>
<PaginationResult>
    <TotalNumberOfPages>0</TotalNumberOfPages>
    <TotalNumberOfEntries>0</TotalNumberOfEntries>
</PaginationResult>
<HasMoreOrders>false</HasMoreOrders>
<OrderArray />
<OrdersPerPage>100</OrdersPerPage>
<PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
<ReturnedOrderCountActual>0</ReturnedOrderCountActual>
</GetOrdersResponse>​`
```

---

The user I am querying for has 2 recent purchases dated at:

- 12/08/11
- 11/18/11

What am I missing here? I am supplying the time range and the call executes properly, yet it finds 0 results. I'd very much appreciate your help.

Comment: It would help if you posted some code.

Comment: you have to offer more information first. what language are you using, some snippets on how you try it at the moment...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I reposted my question with the code I am using. I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the OrderRole, ie. Buyer or Seller and OrderStatus of either Active or Completed. Something like the following will return completed orders for items purchased by the caller.

```
<GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
  <MessageID>cff8bc1c-0475-4d64-a8a5-02757aafd937</MessageID>
  <Version>747</Version>
  <CreateTimeFrom>2012-01-07T14:05:24.6353866Z</CreateTimeFrom>
  <CreateTimeTo>2012-02-07T14:05:24.6353866Z</CreateTimeTo>
  <OrderRole>Buyer</OrderRole>
  <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
</GetOrdersRequest>
```

For more details, have a look [here](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/GetOrders.html).

Answer (score 0):

The maximum date range that may be specified is 30 days